# Meaning of “rubber” in “You might put ME into a Jail, with genteel society and a rubber, and I should never care to come out.”

Tags: meaning, charles-dickens, nineteenth-century-english

In David Copperfield, Mrs Markleham: “You might put ME into a Jail, with genteel society and a rubber, and I should never care to come out.”

What is the meaning of *rubber* here?

Comment: This is answered at the previous question: *rubber* is a card game, such as the [rather genteel] game of bridge.

Comment: In the context of the card game called whist, a 'rubber' is three games played one after the other. A German translation says 'und einem Rubber Whist' which supports this.

Comment: Was *rubber* actually used to mean the card game *Whist* (*David Copperfield* is too early for Bridge).  Or a set of Whist players?  Neither the OED nor the other answer seems to indicate this.

Comment: Googling "a rubber" in 19th-century Google books does seem to show that *rubber* could be used in this way, though. Not for the card game itself, I don't think, but certainly for the set of four people playing it.

Comment: The question was inappropriately closed. The duplicate does not deal properly or completely with the possible use of rubber “ - A contest consisting of a series of matches.” See https://www.charlesdickenspage.com/charles-dickens-glossary.html#R

Answer (score 1):

***Early use of 'rubber' in games or contests of skill***

The word *rubber* has been in use in connection with gaming or contests of skill for more than 400 years. Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kyRWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT596&dq=bow+and+scrape&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T0X-VMyMPJLuoAT1vYBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBzge#v=snippet&q=%22game%20a%20contest%22&f=false) (1755) offers this relevant definition of the term:

> **RUBBER.** *n. s.* {from *rub*.} ... 4. A game ; a contest ; two games out of three. [Examples:] The ass was to stand by, to see two boobies try their title to him by a rubber of cuffs. [—]*L'Estrange*. If butchers had the manners to go to sharps, gentlemen would be contented with a rubber at cuffs. [—]*Collier*.

*L'Estrange* is Roger L'Estrange (1616–1704), and the quotation comes from "[An Ass and Two Travellers](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A26505.0001.001/1:12.3?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber)" in *Fables of Æsop and Other Eminent Mythologists with Morals and Reflexions* (1692):

> A Couple of *Travellers* that took up an Ass in a Forrest, fell downright to Loggerheads, which of the Two should be his Master: So the *Ass* was to stand by, to see those Two Boobies try their Title to him by a **Rubber** at Cuffs. The *Ass* very fairly look'd on, 'till they had Box'd themselves a Weary, and then left them both in the Lurch.

*Collier* is Jeremy Collier (1650-1726), and the cited quotation comes from his essay "[Of Duelling](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A33912.0001.001/1:13?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=rubber+at+cuffs)" (1694):

> *Philalethes*. So that I perceive if Butchers had but the Manners to go to *Sharps*, Gentlemen would be contented with a **Rubber** at Cuffs. If they must be singular in their Disputes, let it be for the better I beseech
> you.

In this sentence *Sharps* refers to pointed weapons, and *Cuffs* to fisticuffs.

Earlier than either of the instances that Johnson cites is this one from a 1667 translation of Quevedo's [*The Visions of Dom Francisco de Quevedo Villegas, Knight of the Order of St. James*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A56893.0001.001/1:9?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=rubber+at+cuffs)"

> You must know, that *He that made the Escape, and the Catchpole are a Couple of Ancient Friends, and Pot-Companions*. Now the *Catchpole* quarrels the *Thief* for not giving him a snip in the last Booty; and the *Thief*, after a great struggle, and a good lusty **Rubber** at Cuffs, has made a shift to save himself. You'l say the Rogue had need of Good heels, to outrun this *Gallows-Beagle*; for *there's hardly any Beast will outstrip a Bayliff that runs upon the View of a Quarry*.

And earlier still is this allusion to "a rubber at cuffs" in jest, in Richard Brathwaite, [*Ar't Asleepe Husband? A Boulster Lecture*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A16650.0001.001/1:8..10?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber) (1640):

> Out of this precious Mine, was, surely, that good Burgomasters wife cut out, who ever met her Husband at the Portell with a gentle word in her mouth; a sweet smile on her lippe; a merry looke on her cherry cheeke; a paire of slippers in one hand: and in the other, a **rubber (not at cuffs)** but a Towell to rubbe him after his travaile: whereas that old beldam Thestylis would have exchang'd that rubber with an halter, if shee might have had her will, rather than be bound to such a Taske.

But before any of these "rubbers at cuffs," there were rubbers at other competitions. The earliest instance in the Early English Books Online database appears to involve archery. From Richard Becon, [*Solon His Follie, or a Politique Discourse, Touching the Reformation of Common-weales Conquered, Declined or Corrupted*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A06083.0001.001/1:3?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber) (1594):

> Gentle Reader, with the vnskilful archers of our times, I did first aime and shoote at the publique good and profit, according to the trust reposed in me, and now as one that hath lost his arrowe, and missed his marke, I have at al adventures discharged the second time, to the ende that my second labours may drawe home my first losses, if my hande be fortunate to pearce the secret partes of thy tender and kinde affections, and move in thee a friendly acceptaunce of these my rude labours; if not, looke no more for my returne to accompany the pleasaunt fieldes, and meddowes, for henceforth I take vp my habitation a∣midst the rockes and deserts, where my arrowes may not pearce, nor the strength of my bowe withstand the bitter windes, and the harde and hoary frostes, where I shall no more play the foole with Solon in the market-place, but the wilde man in the desertes. But if thou shalt vouchsafe to recall so vnskilfull an archer againe into the fieldes, I may perhaps winne a bet, that shall pay for the losse of a **rubber**. Receive then, Solon his folly, not as a testimony of his skill, but rather of the goodwil he beareth vnto thee, and his coun∣try, whereof if thou shalt make acceptaunce, the same is thy honour, and not his: which with thy bounty and goodnes, hast now overcome as well the giver, as the gift.

The next-earliest relates to lawn bowling. From Henry Porter, [*The Pleasant Comedy of the Two Angry Women of Abington*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A09857.0001.001/1:4?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber) (1599):

> *Phillip*. Sirra Franke, whilst they [Master Goursey and Master Barnes] are playing [a game at Tables] heere, / Weele to the greene to Bowles.
>
> *Franke*. Phillip content, Coomes come hyther sirra, / When our Fathers part, call vs vpon the greene, / Phillip come, a **rubber** and so leaue.

Likewise, from Nicholas Breton, "[A Dialogue, After a Friendlie Greeting, vpon a Sodaine Meeting, betweene Arnofilo and Tidero](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A68982.0001.001/1:3?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber)," in *Choice, Chance, and Change: or, Conceites in Their Colours* (1606):

> Tidero. ... Yet to bleer the eies of fools he could plaie the knaue with setting on the face of an honest man: this youth in a basket, with a face of Brasse, vpon a little acquaintance (for a little would serue his turne) comes to me, with this salutation: by your leaue sir: It seemes you are a straunger in these partes, but if you can awaie with our countrie sports, will you make one at bowles for a **rubber** or two? we wil play no great game (and yet would hee cheat for a shilling:) No good sir quoth I, I thank you, I am not acquainted with your groūd, & should but pul down a side, & therfore I pray you nowe pardon mee: will you then sir quoth hee haue a reste at Primero, or a game or two at tables: it is the worst thing in the world to stand idle: true sir quoth I, but it is as good be Idle, as ill exercised, and to tell truth, I am no gamster: besides indeede, vnder the shadowe of iesting; I did not like he should iest awaie my mony:

In Jo Cooke, [*Greenes Tu Quoque, or, The Cittie Gallant*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A19260.0001.001/1:4?firstpubl1=1470;firstpubl2=1700;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=a+rubber) (1614), the game appears to be tennis:

> *Enter Spendall, Purseuet, and a boy with Rackets.*
>
> *Spendall*. A Rubber sirra.
>
> *Boy*. You shall sir.
>
> *Spendall*. And bid those two men you said would speak with me, come in.
>
> *Boy*.I will sir.
>
> *Exit Boy.*
>
> *Spendall*. Did I not play this Sett will?

---

***Use of 'rubber' in connection with whist***

The instance of *rubber* that occurs in *David Copperfield* evidently alludes to the card game of whist. Dickens wrote *David Copperfield* in 1849–1850, and by that date the use of *rubber* in connection with that particular game was firmly enough established to justify its mention in contemporaneous dictionaries. For example, Merriam-Webster's [*An American Dictionary of the English Language*](https://archive.org/details/websteramericand00webs/page/966/mode/2up?view=theater&q=%22whist+and+some+other+games%22) (1847) has this relevant entry:

> **RUBBER,** *n.* ... **5.** *In whist and some other games*, two games out of three ; or the game that decides the contest ; or a contest consisting of three games.

And Joseph Worcester, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lCA7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1253&dq=%22At+whist+and+other+games%22+%22two+games+won%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlv9_37uL3AhWMFzQIHUHuAQoQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22At%20whist%20and%20other%20games%22%20%22two%20games%20won%22&f=false) (1960) offers this formulation:

> **RUBBER**, *n.* ... **6.** At whist and other games, two games won out of three, or the last of three games played, which reckoned with another previously won, decides the contest. [—]*Johnson*.

This appears to have been precisely the sense of *rubber* in *David Copperfield*. The explicit connection to whist does not go back much earlier than 1847, however—at least in the United States. Here is the corresponding definition of rubber in Noah Webster, *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828):

> **RUBBER,** *n.* ... **5.** In gaming, two games out of three ; or the game that decides the contest ; or a contest consisting of three games.

As to why *rubber* came to be applied to contests of skill or chance in the first place, the origin is uncertain. Certainly, it has nothing to do with latex or the plant that supplies it, since Joseph Priestly gave that substance the name *rubber* in 1770 because of its ability to erase pencil marks when rubbed on them.

Robert Hendrickson, *Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins*, fourth edition (2008) has this entry for *rubber match*:

> **rubber match.** A *rubber match* or *rubber game* or simply *rubber* in any sport means a deciding contest between two tied opponents. The term dates back to the early 16th century but no one seems certain of its etymology or in what sport it originated. The expression was not use in card games until the mid 18th century, and the earliest recorded use of it appears to be a 1599 reference, cited in the *Oxford English Dictionary*, to the game of bowls. The word *rubber* in the term seems to derive from a word of unknown origin, not the resilient substance called "rubber" or the verb "to rub."

The OED's 1599 instance of *rubber* presumably refers to Porter's *Two Angry Women of Abington*, which does indeed involve a game of bowls. But as documented earlier in my answer, that instance of the word is five years younger than Becon's metaphorical use of *rubber* in the context of an archery competition, in the preface to his 1594 treatise, *Solon His Follie*.